# Binary tree algorithm asymptotic analysis problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, asymptotics, binary-trees

Assume we have a perfectly balanced Binary tree.
We have the following algorithm: ***For each passed node, traverse through all its ancestors and then do the same algorithm for the left and right child of the node.***

So, the way I try to find the Big-O complexity is this: There are O(N) nodes in the tree and each has O(log2N) ancestors, so overall we'll have **O(N*log2N)** complexity if we start the algorithm from the root.

Now consider another problem for the same Binary tree: ***For each node, go to its left and right child. If the node doesn't have any children, for each ancestor, go through all the previous ancestors.***

Now my attempt for finding the complexity: We basically keep going through every node until we reach the leafs. There are N/2 leafs in a perfect Binary tree with N nodes and for each leaf we have (log2N) ancestors. Since for each ancestor we have to traverse every previous, the overal compexity when we're on a leaf is O(Log2(N)^2), so overall complexity becomes **O(N*log2(N)^2)**.

The problem is that I think the algorithms basically do the same thing. Why do I get different complexities for them?

Comment: You are confused as to what N is. There are O(N) nodes in the tree, but each does not have $O(log_2N)$ ancestors. Each has $O(log_2h)$ ancestors, where h is the height of the current node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same thing.  Consider some node $x$.  Ask yourself how many times the algorithm does the operation "iterate through all the ancestors of $x$".

The first algorithm does this operation once.  The second algorithm does this operation $k$ times, where $k$ is the number of descendants of $x$.  So, it's no surprise that the second algorithm takes longer: it's doing a lot more repeated work.